# What is the type of os.environ? and Why does it not support viewkeys method

Tags: python

If I print `os.environ`, the output looks like a dictionary. Some posts I read online say that it is a memory based dictionary. 
But it does not support `.viewkeys()` method and tells me that: `_Environ instance does not support this method`. So what is the exact type of `os.environ`. If I try:

```
print type(os.environ)
```

I get `instance` as the answer.

Can please clarify this behavior of `os.environ`?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? The `viewkeys()` method is new in 2.7: http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html?highlight=viewkeys#pep-3106-dictionary-views

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> os.environ.__class__
<class os._Environ at 0xb7865e6c>
```

It is a subclass of [UserDict.IterableUserDict](http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html#UserDict.IterableUserDict).

In python 2.7 the source can be found is in os.py on [line 413](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2145593d108d/Lib/os.py#l413) (Windows) and [line 466](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2145593d108d/Lib/os.py#l466) (Posix). [Here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/137e45f15c0b/Lib/os.py#l439) is the python 3.2 source.

Answer (score 4):

It is an `os._Environ` instance:

```
>>> os.environ.__class__
<class os._Environ at 0x01DDA928>
```

It is defined in Python's library, file `os.py` and cannot be a plain dictionary because updating the dictionary must also update the process's environment. Also the key lookups need to be case insensitive on Windows.

In Python 2.x it subclasses `UserDict.IterableUserDict` which presumably doesn't have the new `viewkeys()` method. In Python 3.x it implements the `MutableMapping` abc but has no other explicit base classes.

Comment: +1 "cannot be a plain dictionary because updating the dictionary must also update the process's environment"

Answer (score 0):

`os.environ` is a mapping object. `dict` is a type of mapping object & `os.environ` is not a `dict`. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through it, first convert it to a dictionary by doing this:

```
environment_items = dict(**os.environ)

for env_key in environment_items:
    print(env_key, environment_items[env_key])
```

Answer (score -1):

os.environ is instance of a class,

try:

```
os.environ.__dict__
```

it will give you all it's attributes..

Comment: __dict__ will give this: encodekey
decodekey
encodevalue
decodevalue
putenv
unsetenv
_data